# Let $K\subset L$ a finite field extension and $G=G(L/K)$ a Galois group of $L$ over $K$ then $|G|\leq[L:K]$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> Let $K\subset L$ a finite field extension and $G=G(L/K)$ a Galois group of $L$ over $K$ then $|G|\leq[L:K]$.

I was trying to show this.

By the Primitive Element Theorem $\exists\alpha\in L$ such that $L=K(\alpha)$. Take $p(x)=irr(\alpha,K)$ (irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ in $K$), $\forall \rho\in G$ we have $\rho(\alpha)\in L$ and $p(\rho(\alpha))=0$. Set:
$$\begin{array}{lccc}
\phi:&G&\longrightarrow&R_p\cap L\\
&\rho&\longrightarrow&\rho(\alpha)
\end{array}$$

But I can't show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. (My ideia is to use the first theorem of isomorphism). Somebody have any hints?

Comment: Wait, if $L$ is not a Galois extension, do you mean the automorphism group instead of the Galois group?

Comment: Are not the same thing?

Comment: Well, usually one reserves the term "Galois group" for Galois extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=K(\alpha)$, as you noted. Any automorphism of $L/K$ is completely determined by the image of $\alpha$. Since the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $n=[L:K]$, this polynomial has at most $n$ roots in a splitting field, and thus $\alpha$ has at most $n$ possible images. Thus, the automorphism group has order at most $n$.